# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS cannot connect to 5Ghz wifi with broadcom bcm43228

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

Nothing happens after I connect to the 5GHz Wifi network. Please show me how I can connect. This question is a follow up to a previous question which was posted on SO as well. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323043

Looks like there is no support for my wifi card on 16.04 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx. 
Should I just ditch 16.04 and take 14.04 instead ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For 16.04 all you need to do is make sure restricted drivers are checked in your software and updates sources and issue the command `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: Running this command made my machine connect to the 5GHz WiFi, before it didn't. Cheers

Comment: @msch I'm glad it worked for you!