# Ubuntu 18.04 don´t show 5ghz wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

So as the title says I can connect to 5ghz wlan. 5ghz networks not showing up in the list.

So this don't work for me: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS cannot connect to 5Ghz wifi with broadcom bcm43228](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771095/ubuntu-16-04-lts-cannot-connect-to-5ghz-wifi-with-broadcom-bcm43228)

- I reinstalled the kernel
- I set my country in etc/default/crda

output from `lspci |grep -i net`:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
```

output from `iwlist chan`:

```
lo        no frequency information.

eno1      no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 32 : 5.16 GHz
          Channel 34 : 5.17 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 54 : 5.27 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 58 : 5.29 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 62 : 5.31 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 66 : 5.33 GHz
          Channel 68 : 5.34 GHz
          Channel 96 : 5.48 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same poblem with Broadcom 43228.
The problem is in the Wireless Access Point.
Change 5Ghz AP frequancy to another.