# Can't see 5Ghz Wlan-Networks on 18.04 LTS WiFi-settings

Tags: networking, wireless

This is somewhat a duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 don´t show 5ghz wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063701/ubuntu-18-04-don%C2%B4t-show-5ghz-wifi). But first there might be some differences and second it isn't solved (the answer on the other post is not understandable to me and not accepted by the contributor).

I have a **FritzBox 7530** which broadcasts on 2.4 and 5 Ghz simultaneously. I assigned each of them a different name and in the Wi-Fi-Tab in the "Settings" only the 2.4Ghz network is showing up.
[The currently connected network is the 2.4ghz one. The 5Ghz is named the same but with a 2 at the end.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7p6M.png)
 I am using a **CSL AC1200 WLAN Adapter AC1200** (https://www.amazon.de/-/en/dp/B01M67XBJ4/ref=psdc_1626220031_t1_B01MR2X5OA) which is supposed to support both 2.4 and 5Ghz. 
Strangely I *am* able so see 5Ghz networks in the fritz.box-browser-interface which should be detected by the same adapter.
[As you can see the networks o2-WLAN84 and o2-WLAN60 are detected at 2.4 and 5Ghz in the browser interface.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X62R2.png)

I already tried setting the domain "DE" in etc/default/crda.

`lspci |grep -i net` gives

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

and `iwlist chan` gives

```
enp5s0    no frequency information.

wlx24050ff6bb2c  17 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

lo        no frequency information.
```

I don't have any issues seeing and connecting to my 2.4Ghz network.

**Edit 1**

output for my adapter from `lsusb`

```
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
```

**Edit 2**

I tried the permanent fix from `heynnema` at [WiFi module 8812AU not working with kernel version >= 4.4.0-28-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832329/wifi-module-8812au-not-working-with-kernel-version-4-4-0-28-generic) and restarted the PC but nothing changed.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use lsusb to get the info on the USB wifi .

Comment: the information is now added, hope it helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WiFi module 8812AU not working with kernel version >= 4.4.0-28-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832329/wifi-module-8812au-not-working-with-kernel-version-4-4-0-28-generic)

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant in the answer by vermagic being incorrect. When I run `modinfo 8812au`, I get `vermagic:  4.15.0-91-generic SMP mod_unload`. How do I know whether this is correct or not?

Comment: @Thomas Was your issue somehow solved?

Comment: @Jemo No, unfortunately not. I'm no longer using the adapter.